# Showing $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ is not isomorphic to $(\mathbb{R},+)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, self-learning

To show: $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ is not isomorphic to $(\mathbb{R},+)$

Now, the equation $x^{2} =3$ has a solution in $\mathbb{R}$, but not in $\mathbb{Q}$.  Hence they are not isomorphic to each other.  Is that right, or do I need to prove something else?

Thanks.

Comment: No multiplication, it is as additive groups.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Which equation then ?

Comment: Your group operation is addition, not multiplication. So the equation $x^2 = 3$ actually means $x + x = 3$, which has solutions in both $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R$. When the group is abelian, and especially if the group operation is the usual addition of numbers, we use additive instead of multiplicative notation to avoid confusion. That is, $x + y$ instead of $xy$ and $2x$ instead of $x^2$.

Comment: @manthanomen which equation will do here ?

Comment: Both have infinite elements .How is cardinality different ?

Comment: If you're unfamiliar with cardinality, try this instead:  Show that the only homomorphism from (Q,+) to (R,+) is i(x)=x.  Then show that this homomorphism is not an isomorphism.

Comment: Not all infinite sets have the same cardinality. You should probably read some basic set theory. Most algebra textbooks have an introductory chapter or appendix which discusses the cardinality of infinite sets. Which book are you using?

Comment: @WillO

Not quite. Take any homomorphism of the form $\phi(x)=kx$ for some $k$.

Comment: @manthanomen the homomorphism is not onto because there is no preimage of squareroot of 3 . Hence it is not isomorphism ? But i donot understand point of checking this

Comment: @manthanomen i mean $f(x)=x$

Comment: @manthanomen even if we could find one homomorphism which is not isomorphism the sets are non isomorphic .Is that reason behind checking this .

Comment: @Eoin --- you're right of course.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In $\mathbb Q$ given $x$ and $y$ there are always non-zero integers $m$ and $n$ so that $mx=ny$.

In $\mathbb R$ this is not always the case, consider $x=\sqrt{2}$ and $y=1$

Comment: I donot know anything about quotient group yet

Comment: I re-wrote it so that it does not use the quotient notation but conveys the same idea.

Comment: Hmmm i see now ..How did you get idea about this

Comment: I saw the thing about the quotients some time ago on the web and I just now realized it can be reworded into this.

Comment: i like the answer .thanks

Comment: @K.Dutta Since you seemed confused by the additive/multiplicative notation distinction, it may be helpful to note that $mx$ here means $x + x + \dots + x$ added together $m$ times, instead of "$m$ times $x$" (remember, no multiplication is defined in $(\mathbb Q, +)$ and $(\mathbb R, +)$).

Comment: @TheEmperorofIceCream Your answer?

Comment: @K.Dutta what manthanomen says is true.

Answer (score 10):

By definition any isomorphism would be a bijection between the underlying sets $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$, but those sets don't even have the same cardinality.

Comment: Why is cardinality different ?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, as one can describe a bijection $\mathbb{Q} \leftrightarrow \mathbb{Z}$, but $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable, which follows from Cantor's celebrated diagonal argument. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncountable_set , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument .

Comment: You can proof that there is a bijection between N and Q, thus same cardinality, the proof for that is actually well doable. 
The proof, that there is no bijection between N and R is more difficult, but in a nutshell it is like this:
Assume there is a bijection, which suffices. Therefore you can write down all numbers containing only the digits 1 and 2 and as there is a bijection between N and R, you can associate to each of them a natural number.
However Axiom of Choice lets you create a sequence of 1 and 2, which is not in this long list of all numbers containing only the digits like 1 and 2.

Comment: @Imago: The axiom of choice?

Comment: Yeah, I think one needs it, because first you assume that you now have all sets of numbers consisting only of the digits 1 and 2 in your lists, such as:
1,111.... ; 2,121.... and so on. 
But somehow you have to be legitimate construct this new set, which is not yet included in your list. The Axiom of Choice allows you to construct a new set out of other sets, as far as I know.

Comment: @Imago:  It is easy to give an explicit description of a real number absent from any given list (with your scheme involving just two digits, go down the diagonal and swap all 1's for 2's and vice versa).  You absolutely do not need the axiom of choice for this.

Comment: True, axiom of seems doesn't seem to be needed, I was wrong, thx for setting that right, Will

Answer (score 8):

Recall that an isomorphism is a bijective homormophism between these two groups. Since bijections preserve the cardinality of a set, and $\Bbb{Q}$ and $\Bbb{R}$ do not have the same cardinality, there is no bijection from one to the other.

Comment: Both have infinite elements .How is cardinality different ?

Comment: @K.Dutta There are different "infinities".